# Can't Get Error Message From Axios Response in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I am writing a mobile application with using React Native. At some part, I need to send a post request and get response including the error part. So, for some certain input, API(my own) returns 409 with a message. Example return:

```
{
    "status": 409,
    "message": "E-mail is already exists!"
}
```

Here, I want to take that message and show to the user. This is what I tried:

```
UserService.signup({ fullName, email, username, password })
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ signUp: true });
    if (response.result) {
      Toast.show(messages.successfulSignUp, {
        backgroundColor: "green",
        duration: Toast.durations.LONG,
        position: Toast.positions.TOP
      });
      this.props.navigation.navigate("SignIn");
    } else {
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    Toast.show(error.message, {
      backgroundColor: "red",
      duration: Toast.durations.LONG,
      position: Toast.positions.TOP
    });
    this.setState({ signUp: false });
  });
```

I tried `error.message, error.response, error, error.data` keys, but it always says `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'error.message')`. So, how can I get the message from error object?

---

Edit: This is how I send the request:

```
import { post } from "./api";

export default {
  signup: ({ fullName, email, username, password }) => {
    return post("/user/register", { fullName, email, username, password });
  }
};

export const request = config => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axiosInstance
      .request({
        url: config.url,
        method: config.method || "get",
        data: config.body,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-Auth-Token": store.getState().auth.token
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        resolve(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error.data);
      });
  });
};

export const post = (url, body = {}) => {
  return request({
    url,
    body,
    method: "post"
  });
};
```

Comment: You can log all the keys and see if there's one you're looking for: `for (key in error) console.log('key', key)`. If you can't find the key then you're probably not sending the correct response from your api.

Comment: Could you try `JSON.stringify(error)` ?

Comment: @Vishnudev As I said, it returns undefined

Comment: There should be something wrong with your service, Is it returning a `Promise` @JollyRoger?

Comment: @Clarity It did not enter the for loop. No I am sending the right response because I print what I return in my web service and there is no problem.

Comment: @hongdevelop It returned `undefined` as well.

Comment: @Vishnudev I wrote exactly what it returns, I am not sure what a Promise is.

Comment: @JollyRoger I suggest you add your backend code, which returns the response, to the question.

Comment: @Clarity I do not think that is a good idea since it is not exactly relevant with the code. I can clearly see the response returning from web service and it is same with the one in the question.

Comment: @Vishnudev That is correct, it returns: `[object Object]`. When I stringify it, it returns this: `{"_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null}`.

Comment: See. There is the problem. It should have been `[object Promise]` for you to use `.then`. It is the problem with `UserService.signup` function. The above code has nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: @Vishnudev Thank you for identifying the problem. What do you suggest? I also added the way I send request.

Comment: As I said, Look up `UserService.signup` and Read about [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: That helps, But I'm not familiar with axios. So, wait for someone else to help you. Delete all unwanted code and comments above. Rephrase your question. @JollyRoger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue. I had to change my request method and the way I reach out to the error:

```
export const request = (config) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axiosInstance.request({
            url: config.url,
            method: config.method || 'get',
            data: config.body,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Auth-Token': store.getState().auth.token,
            }
        }).then(response => {
            resolve(response.data)
        }).catch(error => {
            reject(error.response)
        })
    })
}

// This is how reach out to the error message:
console.log(error.data.message);
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what the backend returns, the error message in axios is in `response.data` of the error object.

```
.catch(error => {

    const errResponse = (error && error.response && error.response.data) 
     || (error && error.message); 

    reject(errResponse);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not worked. It returns this: `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:1): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluationg 'error.response')`

Comment: see a demo here https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/sadistic-truffle

Comment: I see, but when use this code, I got `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:1): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluationg 'error.response.data'` error.